# Add a meta field to the list of results for a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, metabox, post-meta

I've created a Custom Post Type for "Books" ... I've also added several meta fields (custom fields) to each book, and I'd like to be able to display some of those fields in the table of results.

Is there a way to hook into the data table and add the custom fields?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple filters for that.  I wrote a [tutorial about adding custom columns](http://pmg.co/wp-list-table-tutorial), which is where the code below is from. The example is adding a column to the 'page' post type that displays the page's template.

You can hook into `load-edit.php` and use `get_current_screen` to grab the correct screen ID's/filters.  From there you hook into `manage_{$screen->id}_columns` and `manage_{$screen->post_type}_posts_custom_column`

```
<?php
add_action('load-edit.php', 'pmg_ltt_load');
function pmg_ltt_load()
{
    $screen = get_current_screen();

    if(!isset($screen->post_type) || 'page' != $screen->post_type)
        return;

    add_filter(
        "manage_{$screen->id}_columns",
        'pmg_ltt_add_columns'
    );

    add_action(
        "manage_{$screen->post_type}_posts_custom_column",
        'pmg_ltt_column_cb',
        10,
        2
    );
}
```

`manage_{$screen->id}_columns` is what actually adds the column and `manage_{$screen->post_type}_posts_custom_column` is your callback.

Add the column:

```
<?php
function pmg_ltt_add_columns($cols)
{
    // pay attention to the key, you'll use it later.
    $cols['template'] = __('Page Template', 'pmg-list-table');
    return $cols;
}
```

And the callback function will get two argument: the column key (what you used above!) and the post ID. Check to make sure it's the column you want, then use `get_post_meta` (or whatever else appropriate to the situation) to fetch the stuff you want to display.

```
<?php
function pmg_ltt_column_cb($col, $post_id)
{
    static $templates;

    if('template' == $col)
    {
        if(empty($templates))
            $templates = array_flip(get_page_templates());

        $tmp = get_post_meta($post_id, '_wp_page_template', true);
        if($tmp && isset($templates[$tmp]))
        {
            echo esc_html($templates[$tmp]);
        }
        else
        {
            esc_html_e('Default Template', 'pmg-list-table');
        }
    }
}
```